# Hierarchical Product Url (with Category Breadcrum in the URL) in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

Hierarchical Product Url (with Category Breadcrum in the URL) in `nopCommerce`

How can i create url structure in `nopcommerce 3.5` like this

> www.mystore.com/category/subcategory/productname?

How to create this url anchor tag?